# Javascript Code to include an image in a search result

Tags: javascript, html, css, search

I am trying to display an image alongside search results in a container that works well to display related search results but I think my javascript-based search engine code for displaying that image has got a problem, please help.

```
var tipuesearch = {
  "pages": [
    {
      "title": "Flash",
      "image": "C:Users/user/Documents/pages/Images/Flash.jpg",
      "text": "The Flash is a trilling science fiction movie, based on Barry Allen",
      "url": "C:/Users/user/documents/resizable/Flash.html"
    }, 
  ]
};
```

Answer (score 1):

To access your image and url you need either :

1. fs npm package (available through Node.js on serverSide or Webpack on clientside)
2. use a local webserver like WAMP, XAMPP and make changes to the file accordingly

```
var tipuesearch = {
  pages: [
    {
      title: 'Flash',
      image: 'http://localhost:8080/pages/Images/Flash.jpg',
      text:
        'The Flash is a trilling science fiction movie, based on Barry Allen',
      url: 'http://localhost:8080/resizable/Flash.html'
    }
  ]
};
```

Comment: Nice try to answer, I leave an upvote, I hope to see you a lot on Stack Overflow. Good Luck

Comment: Lemme try to use a local server and see whether it will work

Comment: changing the code from being double quoted to single quoted will effect changes?

Comment: Got any inofrmation on styling the title to make it look more appealing? i know this is advanced web design